# How to convert date to desired format?

Tags: javascript, momentjs

Given date in ISO-8061: `"2021-06-11T13:12:42.777"` I would like to convert it to format `dd/HHmm'Z'` which is 11/1312Z (or z, whatever).
I have tried:

- `console.log(moment(date).tz('UTC').format('DD/HHmm') + 'z')` which prints `11/1112z`
- `console.log(moment(date).format("DD/HHmm'Z'"))` which prints `11/1312'+02:00'` which is good, but I do not want this '+02:00'

This date is UTC timezone.

Comment: Why isn't the first one what you want?

Comment: @fynsta becuase 11;12 is not UTC. Should be 13:12 UTC.

Comment: Did you try `moment(date).tz('UTC').format('DD/HHmmZ')`?

Comment: What's the result you are looking for?

Comment: @M.HassanNasir just a simple format (without spliting, becuase I know that it can be done easier) which will print `11/1312z` from date a put in question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created a fiddle for you, have a look.
https://jsfiddle.net/muof5aLq/

```
var date = "2021-06-11T13:12:42.777";
var now = moment(date).format('DD/HHmm') + 'z';
console.log(now);
```

Prints

`"11/1312z"`